# Angular2 x-i18n error: Unexpected value imported by the module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have a project on Angular2 (v2.2.1) and TypeScript and i use Angular CLI (1.0.0-beta.21) for it. It works fine. Now i want to add multilanguage support with Angular i18n. Followed by instuctions from official docs i installed this packages:

`npm install @angular/compiler-cli @angular/platform-server --save`

and i ran this command:

`"./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n" -p src/tsconfig.json`

It returned me error message:

```
Error: Unexpected value 'SharedModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'
at D:\Projects\courier-landingpage\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14675:33
at Array.forEach (native)
at CompileMetadataResolver._loadNgModuleMetadata (D:\Projects\courier-landingpage\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14660:51)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getUnloadedNgModuleMetadata (D:\Projects\courier-landingpage\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14636:23)
at addNgModule (D:\Projects\courier-landingpage\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12944:43)
at D:\Projects\courier-landingpage\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12957:16
at Array.forEach (native)
at _createNgModules (D:\Projects\courier-landingpage\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12956:28)
at analyzeNgModules (D:\Projects\courier-landingpage\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12700:16)
at Object.analyzeAndValidateNgModules (D:\Projects\courier-landingpage\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12704:20)
```

Is there any way to solve this error or come other it to continue work on internationalization?

Listing for my AppModule:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';

import { HomeComponent } from './landing/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './landing/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './landing/signup/signup.component';
import { SignupProfileComponent } from './landing/signup/signup-profile/signup-profile.component';
import { SignupVehicleComponent } from './landing/signup/signup-vehicle/signup-vehicle.component';
import { SignupAreaComponent } from './landing/signup/signup-area/signup-area.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    SignupProfileComponent,
    SignupVehicleComponent,
    SignupAreaComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'signup',
        component: SignupComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            children: [
              {
                path: 'profile',
                component: SignupProfileComponent
              },
              {
                path: 'area',
                component: SignupAreaComponent
              },
              {
                path: 'vehicle',
                component: SignupVehicleComponent
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
      }
    ]),
    TextMaskModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Listing for SharedModule:

```js
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

    import { NotificationService, NotificationStream } from './notification.service';
    import { HttpClientService } from './api/http-client.service';
    import { AuthService } from './api/auth.service';
    import { CitiesService } from './api/cities.service';

    import { City } from './models/city';
    import { Notification } from './models/notification';
    import { NotificationType } from './models/notification-type.enum';

    import { NotificationComponent }   from './components/notification/notification.component';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule,
        BrowserModule
      ],
      exports: [
        NotificationComponent
      ],
      declarations: [NotificationComponent],
      providers: [
        HttpClientService,
        AuthService,
        CitiesService,
        NotificationStream,
        NotificationService
      ],
    })
    class SharedModule { }

    export {
      SharedModule,
      City,
      Notification,
      NotificationType,
      HttpClientService,
      AuthService,
      CitiesService
    }
```

P.S.: I found many issues on GitHub related with this error, but neither solution works for me.

Comment: do you have a public git repo where we can reproduce the problem? This would help a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately code above is all what i can provide in public access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution, that works for me. In my SharedModule i removed SharedModule class from final export expression and add 'export' keyword right after NgModule decorator. So my SharedModule now:

```js
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

    import { NotificationService, NotificationStream } from './notification.service';
    import { HttpClientService } from './api/http-client.service';
    import { AuthService } from './api/auth.service';
    import { CitiesService } from './api/cities.service';

    import { City } from './models/city';
    import { Notification } from './models/notification';
    import { NotificationType } from './models/notification-type.enum';

    import { NotificationComponent }   from './components/notification/notification.component';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule,
        BrowserModule
      ],
      exports: [
        NotificationComponent
      ],
      declarations: [NotificationComponent],
      providers: [
        HttpClientService,
        AuthService,
        CitiesService,
        NotificationStream,
        NotificationService
      ],
    })
    export class SharedModule { }

    export {
      City,
      Notification,
      NotificationType,
      HttpClientService,
      AuthService,
      CitiesService
    }
```

Then i moved a bit firther to find a reason of this problem, and what i've discovered.
Angular CLI uses Webpack to compile bundle and ngc uses TypeScript compiler. So I assumed that problem may be in TypeScript compiler, that does not work properly with class decorators. Latest TypeScript compiler version is 2.1.4 and Angular CLI uses 2.0.x version. I checked this and after update TypeScript compiler to 2.1.4 this problem is gone.